# Can "Speccy" be used to merge 2x different website OpenApi's into a single file?

Tags: node.js, openapi

I have a number of microservices, each one with their own OpenApi 'swagger' json file / schema.

I'm trying to merge them all into a single file, which can then be made public. This means any consumers would only require one 'SDK' to download/use.

I'm looking at trying to use `speccy` (https://speccy.io/) for this, but not sure if this is the right tool.

So to keep this question on track and targetted (versus, some opinioned / off topic question):

=> **Can Speccy be used to merge multiple OpenApi schema's into a single one, where the schema's are unique URL's** (versus, a number of local files).

Answer (score 4):

> Can Speccy be used to merge multiple OpenApi schema's into a single one, where the schema's are unique URL's (versus, a number of local files).

No, Speccy has a "resolve" function to handle a single OpenAPI spec split into multiple local files. It does not merge two separate OpenAPI specs.

As an alternative, you can try merging multiple OpenAPI specifications into a single OpenAPI document using APIMatic's online [API Transformer](https://apimatic.io/transformer). This requires you to upload a ZIP file containing the multiple API specification documents structured as described here: https://docs.apimatic.io/manage-apis/api-merging/#merging-two-api-specifications---a-basic-example . If you are looking to automate the process, APIMatic has an API too: https://www.apimatic.io/docs/api#/http/api-endpoints/transformation/transform-via-file

If you import your ZIP file instead of transforming it you can also auto-generate a single SDK for all those files as described here: https://docs.apimatic.io/manage-apis/api-merging/#importing-the-zipped-file-for-sdkportal-generation